# Microsoft Dynamics compling Symmetry error

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, symmetry

I have a problem with the **compiler**, it does not recognize symmetry classes:
for example if I open the class PayrollCalculatePayStatementBenefits and I type an empty space and save the compiler shows a **syntax error** on the line 12 (Class declaration).

```
Symmetry.taxEngine.BenefitInfo benefitInfo401_403;
```

But before doing this action the hole process of paystatements generation was working fine 
after saving the same code it does pay statement generation process dons not work any more showing and error

> "absence of an executable code in path of the class"

I think it's a server configuration problem because if create a job and type Symmetry the the compiler does not propose the Symmetry class in the suggestion list, but I used to work on an other server in an other machine and it does , I don't understand ...

Answer (score 2):

I just got this problem on AX 2012 R3 CU8. 22 compile errors on a brand new and clean installation...

It can be solved by adding a reference to ste-net.dll in the AOT.
This DLL file can be found in the client bin folder.

I found the solution 
[here](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/126055.aspx)